# How to provide alternative urls for dependencies in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, pyproject.toml

Can you list multiple urls for pip to try to find a package at in `pyproject.toml` (or "legacy" configuration files like `setup.py`)?

I'm thinking something like:

```ini
[project]
name='my_project'
dependencies = [
   'library_package@{git+https://path_to_git_repo OR git+https://path_to_alternative_git_repo}'
]
```

The reason I'd find this useful is that I need my package to work in two different isolated corporate networks which have their own git bitbucket server, with a different url. It would be nice if I could maintain a single version of my package's `pyproject.toml` that can pull its dependencies correctly from either network's git repository.